# Shell heredoc inside php heredoc

Tags: php, bash, shell, heredoc

I have something similar to this in a php script:

```
<?php
...
function log() {
    // saving the log into a file.
    exec(<<<BASH
cat >> $logFile <<EOF
$log
EOF
BASH
    );
}
...
```

As you can see the two heredocs (BASH is php and EOF is shell) end as one would think is correct, but when I read the log created the log has something like this:

```
...
my logged string of an important event
EOF
my logged string of another important event
EOF
...
```

And I check the apache log and it has the following  entries:

```
sh: line 1: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please, I am aware that there are many other implementations, such as using php functions or using quotes instead of heredocs. But I am curious about why in this particular case this does not work.

EDIT.
I clarified the code so it is more clear that I am talking about php running shell commands.

Comment: `<<<BASH` is a here-string and not a `here-doc`. `Here-string` doesn't require a delimiter to mark its end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer for PHP case**

Suppose we have `test.php` file with the following contents:

```php
<?php
function mylog() {
  $logFile = 'test.log';
  $log = 'test';

  exec(<<<BASH
cat >> $logFile <<EOF
$log
EOF
BASH
     );
}

mylog();
```

Then `php test.php` produces the right thing(!):

```bash
rm -f test.log
php test.php
cat test.log
```

*Output:*

```
test
```

Now let's indent the Bash part:

```php
<?php
function mylog() {
  $logFile = 'test.log';
  $log = 'test';

  exec(<<<BASH
  cat >> $logFile <<EOF
  $log
  EOF
BASH
     );
}

mylog();
```

Now `php test.php` produces exactly what you've written about in your
question:

```bash
rm -f test.log
php test.php
cat test.log
```

*Output:*

```
sh: line 2: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
  test
  EOF
```

Apparently, you have your Bash part indented, which is an invalid Bash syntax. So you just need to remove indentation for the Bash part. At least, `EOF` shouldn't be indented.

**Original answer where I thought the OP meant pure Bash**

`exec` executes a command, but you need to evaluate bash expression. So you need `eval` instead.

To construct the command using `eval` use the following:

```bash
eval "$(
cat <<'EOF'

cat >> test.log <<EOF2
log contents
EOF2

EOF
)"
```

So we constructed a Bash variable with `"$(` and `)"`. Within the variable we created a here-doc string with `cat <<'EOF'` and `EOF`, where single quotes disable parameter substitution so we can enter literal text.(no evaluation). Then we've written `log contents` by means of another here-doc string created with `<<EOF2` and `EOF2`.

We might save save the Bash variable, then use it as many times as we like:

```bash
cmd="$(
cat <<'EOF'

cat >> test.log <<EOF2
log contents
EOF2

EOF
)"

rm test.log
eval "$cmd"; eval "$cmd"; eval "$cmd"
cat test.log
```

*Output:*

```
log contents
log contents
log contents
```

See docs for [here documents](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Comment: the [tldp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html) Bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong. I recommend [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) instead.

Comment: did I miss something or there is no php going on at all in this answer?

Comment: @santiagoarizti, ah, yes. Somehow, I thought of pure Bash. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: strange, maybe you are right, I must have had some indenting going on. I will mark this as correct, thank you